# Change success page

Tags: checkout, php

everybody!

I need to add this

```
<img src="//cdsusa.veinteractive.com/DataReceiverService.asmx/Pixel?journeycode=22DB0E55-C091-431A-BA44-C1928F926B50" width="1" height="1"/>
```

To my success page

I googled it and found that the change has to go on success.phtml in
/app/design/frontend/MYTEMPLATE/default/template/checkout/

But I simply cant get it to work!! Can anybody help me, please?

My file is like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>

<?php
 session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['sessiongiftwrapper']))
{
$order=$this->getOrderId();
$getvalue=$_SESSION['sessiongiftwrapper'];
$resource = Mage::getSingleton ( 'core/resource' );
$read = $resource->getConnection ( 'core_read' );


$table=$resource->getTableName('sales_order_giftwrap_message');

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');


$write->query("insert into ".$table ." values(".$order.",'".$getvalue."')");
$_SESSION['sessiongiftwrapper']='';
}
?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__('Your order has been received.') ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Thank you for your purchase!') ?></h2>

<?php if ($this->getOrderId()):?>
<?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder()) :?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getViewOrderUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()))) ?></p>
<?php  else :?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Your order # is: %s.', $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId())) ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('You will receive an order confirmation email with details of your order and a link to track its progress.') ?></p>
<?php if ($this->getCanViewOrder() && $this->getCanPrintOrder()) :?>
    <p>
        <?php echo $this->__('Clique <a href="%s" onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'">aqui para imprimir</a> uma cópia de sua compra.', $this->getPrintUrl()) ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
    </p>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if ($this->getAgreementRefId()): ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Your billing agreement # is: %s.', sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementUrl()), $this->escapeHtml($this->getAgreementRefId())))?></p>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if ($profiles = $this->getRecurringProfiles()):?>
<p><?php echo $this->__('Your recurring payment profiles:'); ?></p>
<ul class="disc">
<?php foreach($profiles as $profile):?>
<?php $profileIdHtml = ($this->getCanViewProfiles() ? sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $this->escapeHtml($this->getProfileUrl($profile)), $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id'))) : $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'reference_id')));?>
    <li><?php echo $this->__('Payment profile # %s: "%s".', $profileIdHtml, $this->escapeHtml($this->getObjectData($profile, 'schedule_description')))?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
<?php endif;?>

<div class="buttons-set">
    <button type="button" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
</div>

<?php
echo '
<img src="//cdsusa.veinteractive.com/DataReceiverService.asmx/Pixel?journeycode=22DB0E55-C091-431A-BA44-C1928F926B50" width="1" height="1"/>
';
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to `echo` the `<img>`, just place it like any other HTML. Also, you won't see that image since it is just a tracking pixel. To know it's there make sure you empty your cache and you can view page source with (likely) F12 in your browser.

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: You should never manually call `session_start` in Magento http://alanstorm.com/magento_sessions_early

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to edit a phtml necessarily. If you are not really familiar with Magento (coding side) you could use a widget to add html to that page.

Just create a widget and link it to a CMS block, add a layout update with option specified page.

If you insist on doing it in the phtml I advise you to check the package and the theme set in system configuration in the design section, this might be different from the place where you adjusted your phtml.

Comment: This is a stellar use of widgets.

Answer (score -2):

I got it!

There is an modeule for 'boleto' payment method that added another success.phtml and that was the phtml being loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: you could use template path hints to avoid problems like this, it will make your life easier trust me :D